# Should I return EntityNotFoundException for empty result in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

In a Spring Boot app, I created a global exception handler class using `@RestControllerAdvice` as shown below:

```
@Slf4j(topic = "GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_HANDLER")
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {-

    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatus status,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(), VALIDATION_ERROR);
        for (FieldError fieldError : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errorResponse.addValidationError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException ex,
                                                                WebRequest request) {
        log.error(ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, ex);
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllUncaughtException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        log.error(UNKNOWN_ERROR, ex);
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, UNKNOWN_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildErrorResponse(Exception ex,
                                                      HttpStatus httpStatus,
                                                      WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, ex.getMessage(), httpStatus, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildErrorResponse(Exception ex,
                                                      String message,
                                                      HttpStatus httpStatus,
                                                      WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(httpStatus.value(), message);
        if (printStackTrace && isTraceOn(request)) {
            errorResponse.setStackTrace(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).body(errorResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
            Exception ex,
            Object body,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, status, request);
    }
}
```

I have a service method as shown below:

```
private List<Employee> findByName(String name) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeRepo.findByName(name);
 
    // At this stage, should I check if the result is empty list and then throw exception?
    if (employees.isEmpty()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Not found any employee");
    }

    return employees;
}
```

Before returning employee list, should I check if the result is empty list and then throw exception?

Comment: @Closures Why close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the situation and what you want to achieve with this.
It is a way to show the requesting client that there are no employees with the requested name. You should replace the "runways.isEmpty()" with "employees.isEmpty()" tho, otherwise you might get a error on the building process.

Since you're already using a custom ExceptionHandler, you easily throw the Exception and then interrupt the exception message with your own custom exception message.

Other option without throwing an Exception is, that you can just return the empty list and if you're having a FE application, you can make a check if the list is empty or not and corresponding to that you would show an appropriate message to the client.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information. Actually I will use Postman, not any FE app and for this reason I thought it would be good idea to show a error message (as warning of course indicating the result is empty) in the response entity. Any idea?